# How do I dig peat to avoid getting grass to come with it?

Tags: peat

What do I need to do so that I can dig up some peat without having the grassroots to sprout when the plant is in the ground, because I live on the edge of a peat bog area, and was planning to dig my own peat for planting?

Comment: Are you sure that digging peat is allowed where you live? Where I live, I'd be probably violating half a dozen laws ...

Comment: It's a little bit in (i.e. 2-4 feet) from a creek on swampy grassland.

Comment: http://sianthom.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/the-tradition-of-peat-cutting.html